# SwiftUI fullscreen from subview

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How can I have a subview take the whole screen? Specifically, I'm trying to create a video player view with custom overlay that'll take the whole screen on rotation.

I tried messing around with UIScreen.main.bounds and ignoresSafeArea, but they are still confined to the bounds of the parent view.
I also tried using `enterFullScreenAnimated`, but it doesn't allow for the custom overlay.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fullscreencover(ispresented:ondismiss:content:) ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apple offers [`fullScreenCover`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fullscreencover(ispresented:ondismiss:content:)) as a way to present a view overlaying the rest of your UI. If you are happy with the way it presents itself (eg sliding up like a drawer/sheet for iOS) then it's probably best to use that.

So far as I know, other than `fullScreenCover` there is no way to have a Subview directly define (as a sub-view) something that will overlay the whole screen. At best, you can make it overlay its siblings (and all their descendants), but you cannot overlay something onto your cousins, parents, nor beyond, in a view hierarchy.

As a workaround, though, you could put a ZStack at the top of the view hierarchy and reach up to it using state variables to overlay something over everything else, conditional to the value of that state. If you have the luxury of controlling the entire view hierarchy, and have no qualms about wiring things up this way, this is a good option.

For the use case you described, this seems like it might work well. You simply need to set a State variable to true when the orientation is landscape, and have that state drive the presentation of the overlay view. Of course, you can use animationBlocks and transition APIs to customise how the overlay is presented too, using this method.

Here is some code to show you what I mean in both cases (using `fullScreenCover` and a conditional in the ZStack at the top of the hierarchy):

```swift
// The view that will be presented as the overlay view
struct OverlayView: View {
    @Binding var presenting: Bool
    var color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("A full-screen modal view.")
                .font(.title)
            Text("Tap to Dismiss")
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(color)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .onTapGesture {
            presenting = false
        }
    }
}

// This View defines a button that will use the .fullScreenCover API
// to present a view over the whole screen
struct ButtonForAPIMethod: View {
    @State private var showAPIOverlay = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Overlay Using API") {
            showAPIOverlay = true
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showAPIOverlay) {
            OverlayView(presenting: $showAPIOverlay, color: .blue)
        }
    }
}

// This would be your regular top level view for your app, it is separated here
// so you can clearly see how the conditional overlay is wired up relative
// to everything else. For the purposes of this Answer, our app is just a VStack
// with two Buttons in it.
struct AppView: View {
    @Binding var showConditionalOverlay: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ButtonForAPIMethod()
            Button("Overlay Using Conditional") {
                showConditionalOverlay = true
            }
        }
    }
}

// This root view could be built under whatever View hierarchy you already
// have (represented by AppView, above). It simply allows you to overlay a
// view over everything else.
struct RootView: View {
    @State private var showConditionalOverlay = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            AppView(showConditionalOverlay: $showConditionalOverlay)
            
            if showConditionalOverlay {
                OverlayView(presenting: $showConditionalOverlay, color: .green)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that answers your question!